# AutoRenewable InApp Purchase in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Currently in my Project we have two items of AutoRnewable but I am not able to check if what I have implemented and what I have tested will work in Production or not. I have gone through all the problems that ppl are facing for InApp and posted on all the forums but Still I am not feeling confident for my implementation.

As Sandbox environment is very unpredictable and when it is getting renewed is hard to check sometimes It is renewing for 6 times sometimes not. And with TestFlight also the behaviour is same.

- I am verifying subscription using SwiftyStoreKit API and it is giving me information regarding product purchase active state.
- I am storing the expiration date, and then comparing with current date so that I can get to know If it expired or not. (It won't expire in Production Enviornment as it is AutoRenewable)
- And as per my guess if the period is for a month and If I purchase product on 28th March then the expiration date will be 28th April and on 29th April It will automatically give me the new expiration date with 29 May.
- And In between if the purchase is cancelled then the expiration date will be 29th April only.
- Do I need to check Cancellation_date too, or it won’t be necessity as even after cancellation we will allow user to use the features until It actually expires.

So is this going to work perfectly in Production environment ..!!